# Использование GPU для копирования и поиска текстуры на экране

Tags: c++, gpu

Один разработчик сказал, что через C++ реализовал поиск цвета на экране с помощью GPU (Graphic Processor Unit). Возможно ли это сделать и какие методы/библиотеки мне нужно использовать для этого?

Comment: GPU это видеокарта, а не библиотека.

Comment: Дубликат https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1572910/ *"но ест ли кто-то кто знает"* - конечно ест. Стоит начать спрашивать что-то осмысленное.

Comment: Не "unity", а "unit" ("graphics processing unit"). Это просто значит "видеокарта".

Comment: @HolyBlackCat я имел ввиду с помощью нее можно писать что то на c++

Comment: Ну, есть разные библиотеки для работы с видеокартой (webgpu, vulkan, opengl, куча разных). Выбирайте одну и вперед.

Comment: Разбейте задачу на более мелкие. Сперва нужно получить скриншот экрана. Примеров, как это сделать, навалом! Потом нужно осуществить поиск в изображении. Берёте для этого какую-нибудь библиотеку для работы с изображениями и используете (примеров, опять же, полно). Ищите библиотеки по запросам наподобие: "c++ computer vision library", "c++ image processing library".